# Problems with time and the appearance of enemies (Python, Pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, pygame, game-engine

I post this problem a second time, but with more information. My problem is with my code, for some reason a few lines do not work. I am making a tile game in python using the pygame library. If you run the code, you will see that on the screen 1 red square will fly from top to bottom endlessly. The red square is the enemy. I need that after 10 seconds it’s not 1 square that flies, but 2. The `MobY` class is responsible for this, which generates enemies, and in the `Game` class in the `new()` method there is a cycle that creates red squares:

```py
for i in range(self.mobY):
    m = MobY()
    self.all_sprites.add(m)
    self.mobs.add(m)
```

Variable `self.mobY` which is stored in `__init__` is equal to 1, that is, at the same time there can be only 1 red square on the screen. There is also a timer on the screen, the seconds of which are stored in a variable `self.seconds` that is in the method `time()`.
So that after 10 seconds 2 red squares fly across the screen, in theory you need to put these lines of code in the `new()` method:

```py
if self.seconds >= 10:
    self.mobY += 1
```

But I get an error "'Game' object has no attribute 'seconds'", although it is not.
In general, I need that after 10 seconds there will be 1 more squares on the screen.
Here is the code:

```py
import sys
import pygame as pg
import random

#         R    G    B
DARKGREY = (40, 40, 40)
LIGHTGREY = (43, 43, 43)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

WIDTH = 1008
HEIGHT = 768
FPS = 60
TITLE = "TITLE GAME"
BGCOLOR = DARKGREY
TILESIZE = 48


class MobY(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + TILESIZE:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(6, 9)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(1, 15)
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.mobY = 1

    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()

        for i in range(self.mobY):
            m = MobY()
            self.all_sprites.add(m)
            self.mobs.add(m)

    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def time(self):
        self.font = pg.font.Font(None, 50)
        self.font_color = pg.Color('springgreen')
        self.total_seconds = self.frame_count // FPS
        self.seconds = self.total_seconds % 6000
        self.output_string = "TIME: {0}".format(self.seconds)
        self.text = self.font.render(self.output_string, True, self.font_color)
        self.screen.blit(self.text, [10, 10])
        self.frame_count += 1

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.draw_grid()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.time()
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()


g = Game()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get an error "'Game' object has no attribute 'seconds'"

Yes of course, because `self.seconds` is defined in the method `time`  rather than the constructor of the class `Game`. When `new` is invoked the 1st time, then the attribute `self.seconds` doe not exist, because `time` hasn't been invoked before.

Anyway you approach won't work because, the condition `if self.seconds >= 10:` si fulfilled continuously and will cause that `self.mobY` is incremented many times.

---

Use [`pg.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called.
Define the time when the first `MobY` has to be created `self.next_mob_time`. when the time point has exceeded, then create an instance  of `MobY` and increment the time by 10000.

```py
current_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
if current_time > self.next_mob_time:
    self.next_mob_time += 10000
    self.mobY += 1
```

Invoke `new` in time. Furthermore the groups have to be created in the constructor of `Game` rather than in `new`:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(1, 15)
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.mobY = 0
        self.next_mob_time = 0
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()

    def new(self):
        current_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time > self.next_mob_time:
            self.next_mob_time += 10000
            self.mobY += 1
            m = MobY()
            self.all_sprites.add(m)
            self.mobs.add(m)

    # [...]

    def time(self):
        self.new()
        self.seconds = pg.time.get_ticks() // 1000

        # [...]
```